# Add property belongs_to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, entity-relationship

Not sure if I'm doing this right.  Have two models:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :name, :division_id
  belongs_to :divison
  has_many :players
end

class Division < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :teams
end
```

And the migration for :teams includes a foreign_key

```
create_table :teams do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.string :city
  t.integer :division_id
  t.foreign_key :division, dependent: :delete

  t.timestamps
end
```

In my `Teams` index view, I'd like to add the `division` name for each team.  Getting the id is simple, I just use `<%= team.division_id %>`  However, I'm not sure what to do to get the division name.

I tried adding the division to each team:

```
@teams.each do |team|
    team.division = Division.find(team.division_id)
end
```

But this failed, saying: `undefined method 'division=' for #<Team:0x3cf2df0>`.  I'm not even sure if this is the right way to go about doing this, or if I'm over-complicating things.

Comment: <%= team.division.name %> will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the relation, you should be able to just do

```
team.division.name
```

Also, you have a typo in your model (*you would have never missed this kind of error in a statically typed language like Java. In Ruby you have to write tests, lots of tests*)

```
belongs_to :divison
```

Comment: Ahhhh, that's why I didn't have access to division data through team.  Rather than figure that out I attempted to force it with some horrid controller loop.  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, didn't forget, just locked me out because you answered so quickly!